# ion slide is not working when i navigate back in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

**Auto Play Slider is Not Working**

I tried all solutions from the given stack overflow nothing works for me I am using **ionic4 slide**

**I am trying this from last 6 days not getting the solution please let me know proper solution so that I can fix this issue**

```js
 @ViewChild('sliderRef', { static:false }) slides: IonSlides;
 option = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true,
     speed:1000,
     loop:true,
     autoplay:{disableOnInteraction:false}
  }
  ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.sliderThree =
      {
       
        slidesItems: [
          {
            id: "../../assets/images/market.jpg",
            name:"Sumo"
          },
          {
            id: "../../assets/images/mobile.jpg",
            name:"Shelcal 500"
          },
          {
            id: "../../assets/images/test.jpg",
            name:"Orofer Xt"
          },
        ]
      };
      this.slide.update();
      }
 async slideChange() {
     console.log("method called");
    
    this.slides.update();
  
  }
```

```html
<ion-slides [options]="option" #sliderRef (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChange()">
          <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of sliderThree.slidesItems" style="width:90%;height:20vh;" (click)="labTest()">
              <ion-card style="width:90%;height:20vh;
              display:-webkit-box;
              overflow:hidden;border:1px solid grey;"  >
                  <img [src]="item.id" style="width:100%;height:20vh;
                  display:-webkit-box;" alt="">
             </ion-card>
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an similar issue try manually starting on `ionViewDidEnter` and stoping it on `ionViewDidEnter`.

But first remove your loop, and autoplay properties from the options like so:

```
 option = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true,
    speed:1000
  }
```

Then handle start and stop like this:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
   this.slide.startAutoplay();
}

ionViewDidLeave(){
   this.slide.stopAutoplay();
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to make it work between tabs, then use the autoplay option like so:

```
 option = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true,
    speed:1000,
    autoplay: {
       delay: 1000,
       disableOnInteraction: false
    }
  }
```

Comment: but this is not working in tab page my ion slide is in home tab page how to handle this in tab page? i tried this same method not working

Comment: Oh yeah, for tabs it works a little bit different, you have to set the autoplay. I will edit the answer.

Comment: that card image is having click function to next page bro when i come back to this home page tab its not auto sliding how to fix this